To what extent can Magneto harness Earth's magnetic field to recover faster from injuries?
It seems that Magneto can use Earth's magnetic field to recover faster from injuries. What are the extent, potential, healing rate, and limits of this ability?
In X-Men The Animated Series, after hard-wounded Magneto is tossed from Asteroid M by a rebel, the magnetic field of Earth makes him recover and regain consciousness. In Wikipedia I read that Magneto can tap into Earth's magnetic field to increase his physis, stamina, senses, and reflexes.

What exactly are you asking here? You literally gave an example from canon which cries that the answer is yes.

If the animated series is considered canon, then my question is what are the extent, potential and limits of this ability. E.g. can it reach a level like Wolverine's? I rephrased the question.

Talk about power creep...
